# Visual Studio C++ - Whats the difference between the 'CLR' and 'General' categories?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Let's say I'm making a new blank project.

What is the difference between a 'CLR Empty Project' and an 'Empty Project?'

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2010, but I presume the question goes deeper than just one version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you crete an Empty Project, the initial settings for the C++ project will be such that the resulting binary will be "native" code, depending on the processor you've chosen. If you create a CLR empty project, the resulting binary will be a CLR binary, with MSIL rather than machine language. Depending on what how you're going to use your binary, you need to choose the appropriate type.